# Best option for getting feed data from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am having a database design issue and i'm still pretty new to MySQL so I thought I would ask here. What would be the best way to get data for a chronological feed from multiple tables? For example a user does many things, they vote, comment, rate, ask questions. I save all this information in their respective tables "tblVote", "tblRate" etc, now the tricky part. a user can follow a user or many, so say you follow 3-4 people. Following allows you to see their interactions, voting, rating, commenting, asking questions etc in your feed (like facebook or something similar).

What would be the best way to get all the information from all 5 tables for every person they follow and then sort all of that chronologically? I Am assuming my current method (foreach follower grab all votes, comments, ratings etc  and sort all would be terrible)

My working theory, so my working idea is to create a Interaction table, that has a column for the users id, the id of the other tables entry, and a type reference. so for example

**User ID    |    InteractionID    |    Type**

```
 9       1232     Comment


10       80      Rating


9        572     Vote
```

Then you could just go ahead and grab all Interactions for each of the people they follow, sort that and then say grab the top 10? and query the individual databases to get the full info (time of comment, text of comment etc)

Comment: Why not just do a many-to-many relation between User-Follower. Then use regular joins to get all the info you need from those 5 tables, order by datetime_col, and LIMIT 10? I am just wondering what is stopping you from doing what you want to?

Comment: Like I said i'm not super privy on mysql yet, I just assumed grabbing hundreds / thousands of rows per user per table would be crazy resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

A many to many relationship exists between User and Follower. Since, Follower is also another user, this becomes a recursive many-to-many. When you decompose this relationship, you get a Association table or a gerund.

> User_Follower {id, userid_fk, followerid_fk}

Both the userid_fk and followerid_fk are referencing to the `User` table.

Now, I am assuming you have a One-to-many relationship between User-tblRate, User-tblVote, User-tblPost etc.

So, you can write a join something like this:

> select p.postTitle, p.postTag, ...,
>   c.commentId, c.commentData, ...
>
> from (tblUser u  INNER JOIN tblPost p
>
> ON (p.userid = u.userid)) INNER JOIN tblComment c
>
> ON (c.userid =
>   u.userid)
>
> where  u.userid in
>   (select userid_fk from user_follower where followerid_fk = 100)
>
> orderby p.datetime_col ASC, c.datetime_col ASC
>   LIMIT 10;

100 is the user you want to get the information for.

The idea is that you just have one association table linking the `User` and `Follower`, then use simple joins to get the data for all the followees